# How to use the sendPasswordResetEmail() function on the server using the firebase-admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In the past, I have used firebase.auth in the web client and once a user creates another user, I link certain security logic:

- Once the user has been created I send an email to verify your email
  with the function user.sendEmailVerification ().
- As the user was created by another user, I assign a default password
  and use the    sendPasswordResetEmail () function so that the user
  registers his new    password.

That has worked well for me so far, but now **for many reasons I need to move that logic to my server**, for that I'm developing a backend with cloud functions and I'm using the Node.js Firebase Admin SDK version 6.4.0, but I can not find a way to use the functions of user.sendEmailVerification() and sendPasswordResetEmail() to implement the same logic on the server, the closest thing I found was:

- auth.generateEmailVerificationLink (email)
- auth.generatePasswordResetLink (email)

But it only generates a link for each one, which by the way the only emailVerification() serves me, the one from generatePasswordReset always tells me:

> **Try resetting your password again**
>
> Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has
> already been used.

Even though be a new link, and it has not been used.

**My 3 questions would be:**

1. How can I make the sendEmailVerification () and
   sendPasswordResetEmail () functions work on the server?
2. How can I make the link generated with
   auth.generatePasswordResetLink (email) work correctly on the server?
3. Is there any way to use templates and emails on the server that are
   in firebase auth?

Thank you in advance for sharing your experience with me, with all the programmers' community of stack overflow.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. You claim you are having one user create another user but it is not clear whose email is being verified and which is user's password is being reset. Please provide a clear flow and label the emails of each user differently so we can tell them apart.

Answer (score 3):

1. Those functions are not available in `firebase-admin`, but you should be able to run the client-side SDK (`firebase`) on the server as well. Not exactly a best practice, but it will get the job done. There's a long standing [open feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/46) to support this functionality in the Admin SDK. You will find some helpful tips and workarounds there.
2. Could be a bug. I would consider reporting it along with a complete and minimal repro. The Admin SDK does have an [integration test case](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/auth.spec.ts#L373) for this use case, but it works slightly differently.
3. Not at the moment. Hopefully, this will be covered when the above feature request is eventually fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for your links, for the moment I could find this link that will temporarily solve my problems:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-send-password-reset-email
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The is a workaround provided here
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/46

I found a work-around that works well enough for my use case, see below. I'm not sure if this is best practice, but I wanted to keep the emails exactly the same between the server and client requests. Would love to hear about any flaws with this implementation

```
As suggested above, it uses a three step process to do this:

Acquire a custom token via the admin sdk's createCustomToken(uid)
It converts this custom token to an idToken via the API
It invokes the send email verification endpoint on the API
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const apikey = functions.config().project.apikey;
const exchangeCustomTokenEndpoint = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=${apikey}`;
const sendEmailVerificationEndpoint = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=${apikey}`;

module.exports = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  if (!user.emailVerified) {
    try {
      const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.uid);

      const { idToken } = await fetch(exchangeCustomTokenEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: customToken,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      }).then((res) => res.json());

      const response = await fetch(sendEmailVerificationEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          requestType: 'VERIFY_EMAIL',
          idToken: idToken,
        }),
      }).then((res) => res.json());

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(`Sent email verification to ${response.email}`);
    } catch (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it doesn't matter anymore, but I had a headache doing this so I'd like to share even if it isn't the greatest answer.

```
await admin.auth().createUser(
            {email, password, displayName, phoneNumber, photoURL}
        ).then(function(userRecord) {
            admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid).then(function(customToken){
                createdToken=customToken; 
                firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(createdToken).catch(function(error){
                    return console.log(error)
                })
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
                        return console.log('It worked')
                    },function(error) {
                        return console.log(error)
                    })
                  });
            })
        })
```