# How to send email verification when registering a new user in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, email-verification

I am using React-Native for client-side and for Cloud Functions I am using NodeJS. How can I register a user and send a verification email where the user is supposed to open and activate the profile?

This is what U have used in a project where I didn't need to verify emails:

```
exports.createUser = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
     const newUser = {
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: data.password,
        disabled: false
    }

    const userRecord = await admin
        .auth()
        .createUser(newUser);
})
```

but now I need to verify the emails.

I did not find any tutorial in RN. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The Admin SDK (that you use in Cloud Functions) does not have an an option to trigger sending of verification email. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858536/how-to-use-the-sendpasswordresetemail-function-on-the-server-using-the-firebas

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it safe creating new users from the client side than?

Comment: It depends on what you want it to be safe from. But there's nothing inherent to the user creation process in Firebase Authentication that makes it safer to do it with a server-side process than with a client-side process. If there's an API in the client-side SDK for it in Firebase, you can assume it can be used to safely perform the operation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem is that if I decide to host that function in Cloud Functions, how am I suppose to allow users to call it when registering since they are not authenticated yet !?